# Non hubspot form popup not creating contacts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, hubspot

I'm having an issue. I have a website that has non hubspot forms. We already did the tracking code integration to create a cookie for the user and track the session and we enable the non hubspot forms. The problem is, all forms in the website works and create contacts correctly, except the most important, which is the sign up. I think is because this is the only form we display in a modal.

Does anybody had this problem before and know how to solve it?

I can't use a hubspot form, neither the contacts API to create one when a submission occurs in the sign up popup, because we need the right original source of the contact. If we use the hubspot API or a third party integration, the original source will be offline.

We use the same sign up component without a modal somewhere else in the website and that one tracks and create contacts fine. I'm sure the other one doesn't works because is in a modal/popup...

Our website is based on React, NextJs and Chakra UI.

Glad if someone could help me or give me a clue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have gone through this list to exclude any issues listed. If you still find the form isn't submitting, you may need to use the HS API to submit your form data. I suspect that since you're trying to capture on a login/registration page, the password field might be preventing the form capture, or your email field is not set to type="email"

```
Form is not enclosed in <form> tags.
Form is contained inside <iframe> tags.
Form has JavaScript bound to the form submit event or submit button click event. This is how the tool captures submissions and any other events, and can prevent HubSpot from knowing when submissions occur.
Form was introduced after the page completed loading. The tool scans the page as soon as it loads and listens to submissions on forms that were present at that point.
Form is on a single-page app. In most single-page apps, the HTML is not loaded when navigating to another page. As a result, HubSpot cannot capture these form submissions. 
Form contains a sensitive field, such as credit card number.
Form contains hidden fields. The tool does not collect information from any hidden fields.
The email field is not an email type input, as in: <input type="email">.
Form is not using a standard <input type="submit"> button for its form submission. The form must have a standard <input type="submit"> button to capture submissions.
```

https://knowledge.hubspot.com/forms/pop-up-forms-and-non-hubspot-forms-faq#do-non-hubspot-forms-work-with-my-form-builder